# How to use Node.js built-ins like assert from TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I can't seem to get `assert()` to work. From what I understand, this is a built-in of Node.js, but somehow it isn't found. I suspect I have to declare a dependency on Node.js or similar.

In my source file I have:

```
import assert from 'node:assert/strict'
```

And I get error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'node:assert/strict' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

There is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "untitled",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.5.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

and `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

I'm using

- Node.js 18.16.0
- Typescript 5.0.4

Comment: Install `@types/node`?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. I knew I was missing something minor.